# Create blended layer with mask and text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I have a simple text layer and a texture layer. I want to use the texture layer to texture the text using blending modes and opacity.

I want the texture to only show through on the text... but I want to be able to move the texture to find the best look.

I believe this is called a track matte.

I want to be able to also change the font though and have everything work without redoing the process(hence, I can't rasterize the font).

e.g., take a very large texture. Create a text layer. Have the texture show only on the actual text and not any where else. Be able to change the text font, size, etc and be able to move the texture, all without having to redo the process.

(I have no problem being able to do this if I want to rasterize stuff, but then I can't change the font or texture position)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is a clipping mask.

1. Place your texture on layer directly above your text layer in the layers panel
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the dividing line between the two layers.

Your texture is now clipped to the text layer. You can move, edit, transform and do whatever you like to either layer without having to edit or reapply any masks.

[image: Clipping mask]

- [**Photoshop Help / Reveal layers with clipping masks**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/revealing-layers-clipping-masks.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done.

Simply unlink the alpha layer(there is a link chain between the layer and it's alpha) and create the alpha channel corresponding to the text.

This doesn't allow you to move your text and move it's alpha channel too though and one has to recreate the mask when the text or font changes.